# Entity:media doesn't exist error when searching for url in "add link" in wysiwyg

Tags: media, wysiwyg

When adding a link into a rich text field (**wysiwyg**) (see images bellow) and searching for a keyword the throbber icon keeps spinning and that's it.

[image]
[image]

I looked at the error logs and found the following, this was working recently, no idea what happened.

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: "The "entity:media" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\linkit\MatcherManager are: entity:contact_form, email, entity:contact_message, entity:feeds_feed, entity:node, entity:scheduled_update, entity:taxonomy_term, entity:user, entity:file, front_page"
```

If anyone has an idea what happened?
**Drupal 8.7.3**

Comment: It sounds like in your linkit profile "configuration > content authoring > linkit" you may have told it to include media entities and you may have uninstalled the media module/deleted some media entities. Try going into that linkit profile configuration and removing media entities as an option if its there or try resaving the configuration

Comment: @Leigh thanks the idea, but when i go the linkit url i the page fails to load due to the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but not with entity:media, but with entity:shortcut

I ended up by deleting the matcher from the database.

It is in the datatable config under the name "linkit.linkit_profile.ckeditor"

`SELECT * FROM config WHERE name= "linkit.linkit_profile.ckeditor";`

The data is stored in a serialized string. To remove it, you must be confident in editing serialized strings, which is a bit dangerous.

I used [(UN)Serialize.me](https://www.unserialize.me/) to convert the unserialized string to a JSON string, then edited the JSON in [JSON Editor Online](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) and back again.

I first tried to use drush to export the config, editing the config YAML file and then importing, but it yielded the same error.